# How to change background color of selected item in LongListSelecter?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm new to the windows phone development, and I'm now developing a windows phone 8 application.

Would you please tell me that in WPF LongListSelecter, how to change the background color of the selected item？

Better to display the code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the background color or text color of selected item?

If you want to change the color of selected item, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the viewmodel and call `RaisePropertyChanged` event.

The following links are useful tutorials for your learning.

- [Highlight a selected item in the LongListSelector on WP8](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Highlight-a-selected-item-30ced444)
- [LongListSelector in depth | Part1: Visual structure and API](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api)

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use converter to set the selection color of the selected Item or you can use Blend to change the color via XAML